# Spring 3.0 load proprrties file and set @Scheduled cron

Tags: java, cron, spring-3, spring-scheduled

I want to execute a method  every hr which will do my job.

I am using **SPRING 3.0** (please keep in mind) schedule cron below is my code. But it is giving the below error.
**Error** : "Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'scheduling.job.cron'"

ApplicationContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/task 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd ">

<bean

class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
<property name="locations">
    <list>
        <value>classpath:test.properties</value>            
    </list>
</property>
<property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
```

Java Class

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${scheduling.job.cron}")
public void testScheule()
{
    logger.info("Schedule Call" + new Date());
}
```

Properties file (which is present in src/main/resource/test.properties) contain below line

```
scheduling.job.cron=0 0/1 * * * ?
```

Can somebody please help me to get out of this error and work sucessfully.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure you have correctly configured your application.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
 xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/ http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/ http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd">

    <task:annotation-driven />
    <util:properties id="testProps" location="test.properties" />
    <context:property-placeholder properties-ref="testProps" />
    <bean id="yourBeanClassHere" class="com.howtodoinjava.service.YourBeanClassImplHere"></bean>
</beans>
```

Have a look at this link for a better understanding http://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-core/4-ways-to-schedule-tasks-in-spring-3-scheduled-example/

Comment: As my test.properties is in resources folder under maven project so do i need to give resources/test.properties at location ?

Comment: technically spring should check all files located under resources folder by default

Comment: I have tried this but it is not reading the file both way like resources/test.properties or just test.properties :( what can be the other reason

Comment: Are you using this code to run some JUnit test its not?

Comment: No, I haven't any junit test case.. I have my application where I am putting test.properties file and want to do scheduling on that basis.

Comment: could you share then your web.xml file?

Comment: <display-name>My project</display-name>                                <context-param>
    <description>Default configuration</description>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
      classpath:spring/abc.xml
    </param-value>
  </context-param>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/webservice/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

Comment: your <param-value> classpath:spring/abc.xml </param-value> do you have your applicationContext called abc.xml??

Comment: Yes .. Whole application is working i am just adding this scheduler cron tag

Comment: seems fine i would have to debug your code and check why cant find the properties file...i cant help from here

Comment: I have added "/" after the classpath & my file is in /src/resources/*.properties & it started working I have done it with task schedular  <util:properties id="applicationProps" location="classpath:/test.properties" /> 
  <context:property-placeholder properties-ref="applicationProps"  />
  <bean id="testBean" class="com.example.ClassName"></bean>
 
 <task:scheduled-tasks>
    <task:scheduled ref="testBean" method="methodToCall" cron="#{applicationProps['scheduling.job.cron']}" />
 </task:scheduled-tasks>

Comment: @RaviB cool. Sometimes is useful use classpath* and spring will try to find all resources in your resources folder, but great you did it work!

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible in Spring 3.0.
This feature is available ,starting from spring 3.0.1.

Even if you are able to resolve the property scheduling.job.cron from test.properties file, you will receive below exception:-

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cron expression must consist of 6 fields (found 1 in ${scheduling.job.cron})
```

In Spring 3.0, only possible way to do is:-

```
@Service (value="testService")
public class TestService {
// ..

  public void testScheule()  { .. }

}
```

Now you can define in xml like below:-

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.some.package" />
    <task:annotation-driven />
    <util:properties id="applicationProps" location="test.properties" />

<task:scheduled-tasks>
  <task:scheduled ref="testService " method="testScheule" cron="#{applicationProps['scheduling.job.cron']}" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply , But i have given the property in test.properties  as below scheduling.job.cron=0 0/1 * * * ?

Comment: Updated the answer, please check and let me know.

Comment: Not solved...  getting org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [resource/test.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Comment: I tried by  putting    <value>classpath*:/resource/*.properties</value>                        Still Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'scheduling.job.cron'

Comment: Tried your code on my machine and updated the answer with my findings, upgrade to spring 3.01 version to use your desired feature.

Comment: It's not possible for me to do as of now.

Comment: Can you put your test.properties file in the same folder as that of web.xml, and see what you get after running your code. Keep location as classpath:test.properties .

Comment: Not worked getting same error that file not found and unable to read